# Firebase Get All Sub-Nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an android project and my app uses firebase. You can see my firebase structure below. Now my question is how can a retrieve all of these names? I will add them to an `arraylist` and show I a `listview`. I have no problem with listview but i can not get all childs. please help me. thank you so much

[image: MY FIREBASE STRUCTURE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the `names`:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userid=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("useridler").child(userid);

reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String names=datas.child("_name").getValue().toString();

  }
 }
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
 }
});
```

the snapshot is at `child(userid)` then loop inside of it's direct children and get the `_name` values.

Comment: it did not work for me. i have an arraylist named userName. when i write userName.add("something") in the for loop that you wrote it did not respond to me. but when i wrote outside of the loop it works and i can see "something" in my listview.

Comment: you need to write userName.add(names)